# How do change img src.value for upload new image

Tags: upload, image, src

this code isnt work

anyone know how ?

Comment: What's blah in document.blah.image.value... what errors are you getting. And what doesnt work. Be more descriptive.

Comment: blah is form name.

ı want to thumb preview before upload.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using http://jquery.com/ as it provides many function to do things like this, but using CSS style selectors instead of the nasty javascript dom.